# Book library with borrowing support

Tags: java

I decided that in order to get better at programming, I should focus on building and improving simple projects. I have made a library program that contains collections of unique books of varying quantities. Although this runs as expected, I am not satisfied with the potential of expanding it to complexities. What are the ways I can improve the efficiency of this program's code, and allow greater potential of increasing the complexity of it? Thank you.

### Book.java

```
/*
 * This class defines the uniqueness of each individual book
 * that is part of a separate collection
 * 
 */

public class Book {
    
    private boolean borrowed; //Each book is either borrowed or not
    
    public Book() {
        this.borrowed = false;
    }
    
    public void setToBorrowed() { //Method will fire once a book has been checked out
        this.borrowed = true;
    }
    
    public void setToReturned() { //Method will fire once book has been returned to the library catalog
        this.borrowed = false;
    }
    
    public boolean isBorrowed() { //Determines whether the book is borrowed or not
        return this.borrowed;
    }
    
}
```

### BookCollection.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * The purpose of this class is to define a collection of books for different titles
 */

public class BookCollection {

    private int quantity; //Number of copies for each book collection
    
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(); //Collection of individual books
    
    public BookCollection(int quantity) { //Creates a collection of books with a defined # of copies
        this.quantity = quantity;
        for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            books.add(new Book());
        }
    }

    public void addBook() { //Adds a new book object to the collection of books
        books.add(new Book());
    }
    
    public boolean borrowBook() { //Borrows a book from the collection
        for(Book b : books) {
            if(!b.isBorrowed()) {
                b.setToBorrowed();
                return true; //Book has been borrowed successfully 
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All books are borrowed, sorry");
        return false; //Book has failed to be borrowed
    }
    
    public boolean returnBook() { //Returns a book back to the catalog
        for(Book b : books) {
            if(b.isBorrowed()) {
                b.setToReturned();
                return true; //Book has been returned successfully
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Cannot return book at this time, sorry!");
        return false; //Book has failed to be returned
    }
    
    public void printBooks() {
        for(Book b : books) {
            System.out.println("Borrowed? " + b.isBorrowed());
        }
    }
    
    public int getQuantity() { //Returns the # of copies the collection has, borrowed or not
        return this.quantity;
    }
    
}
```

### Library.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * This class is the engine of the program
 */

public class Library {
    
    static Map<BookCollection, String> bookCatalog =
            new HashMap<BookCollection, String>(); //Entire collection of books
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Test BookCollection objects:
        BookCollection book1 = new BookCollection(5);
        BookCollection book2 = new BookCollection(3);
        BookCollection book3 = new BookCollection(2);
        
        bookCatalog.put(book1, "Cracking the Coding Interview");
        bookCatalog.put(book2, "Crime and Punishment");
        bookCatalog.put(book3, "Catch-22");
    
        //Client borrows 2 copies of Catch-22
        borrowBook("Catch-22");
        borrowBook("Catch-22");
    
        
        printCatalog();
        System.out.println();
        
        //Client returns the copies
        returnBook("Catch-22");
        returnBook("Catch-22");
        
        
        //Test if catalog has been updated correctly
        printCatalog();
        System.out.println();
        
    }
    
    /*
     * printCatalog()
     * 
     * Return type: void
     * 
     * This method prints out each collection of books 
     */
    
    public static void printCatalog() { 
        
        for(Map.Entry<BookCollection, String> entry : bookCatalog.entrySet()) {
            
            BookCollection bc = (BookCollection) entry.getKey();
            
            System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getValue());
            bc.printBooks();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * I am sure there is a way to simplify 'borrowBook()' and 'returnBook()' by use of a new method
     * that does what both of these already do (searching for a book title match)
     */
    
    /*
     * borrowBook(String bookTitle)
     * 
     * Return type: void
     * 
     * This method borrows a book from a collection
     */
    
    public static void borrowBook(String bookTitle) { //Borrows a book from the entire library catalog
        
        for(Map.Entry<BookCollection, String> entry : bookCatalog.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().equals(bookTitle)) {
                BookCollection bc = (BookCollection) entry.getKey();
                if(bc.borrowBook())
                    System.out.println("You have successfully borrowed " + bookTitle);
                else
                    System.out.println("All copies of " + bookTitle + " have been checked out already, sorry! :(");
                
                return;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println(bookTitle + " doesn't exist - sorry!");
        
    }
    
    /*
     * returnBook(String bookTitle)
     * 
     * Return type: void
     * 
     * This method returns a book back to the collection of books
     * 
     */

    public static void returnBook(String bookTitle) {
        for(Map.Entry<BookCollection, String> entry : bookCatalog.entrySet()) {
            
            if(entry.getValue().equals(bookTitle)) {
                BookCollection bc = (BookCollection) entry.getKey();
                if(bc.returnBook())
                    System.out.println("You have successfully returned " + bookTitle);
                else
                    System.out.println(bookTitle + " cannot be returned at this time");
                
                return;
                
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(bookTitle + " doesn't exist - sorry!");
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: At first glance, you need to change most of your Library class code from static to non-static.  Creating one instance of Library is more extensible than a static class.  Also, your bookCatalog map belongs in a model class.  The model / view /  controller pattern is powerful when creating a Java application.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I appreciate your comment and will study the MVC design pattern. I was concerned with my map's implementation and its lack of flow with the rest of the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by *Gilbert Le Blanc* there are some useful structural patterns that
can be applied in your case. But one thing at a time.

In your `Library` class there is this comment:

> I am sure there is a way to simplify 'borrowBook()' and 'returnBook()' by use of
> new method that does what both of these already do (searching for a book title
> match)

You are right, there are some improvements that could be made on that part. The
first one I see is the usage of your map; One advantage of a map is to
quickly/efficiently retrieve an item by key. In your case the key is not the
book, but the *title*.

```
private static static Map<String, BookCollection> booksByTitle = new HashMap<>();

// ...

public static void borrowBook(String bookTitle) {
    if ( !booksByTitle.containsKey(bookTitle) ) {
        System.out.println(bookTitle + " doesn't exist - sorry!");
        return;
    }
    
    BookCollection collection = booksByTitle.get(bookTitle);
    if(collection.borrowBook())
        System.out.println("You have successfully borrowed " + bookTitle);
    else
        System.out.println("All copies of " + bookTitle + " have been checked out already, sorry! :(");
}
```

Once done, you see that the two methods `borrowBook` and `returnBook` are similar,
only the operation and message is different. You can then refactor your code to
extract that code :

```
private static void doInCollection(String title, Consumer<BookCollection> operation) {
    if (!booksByTitle.containsKey(title)) {
        System.out.println(title + " doesn't exist - sorry!");
        return;
    }
    operation.accept(booksByTitle.get(title));
}
```

(**Added with edit 1**:)
That you use with :

```
public void borrowBook(String bookTitle) {
    doInCollection(bookTitle, collection -> {
        if (collection.borrowBook())
            System.out.println("You have successfully borrowed " + bookTitle);
        else
            System.out.println("All copies of " + bookTitle + " have been checked out already, sorry! :(");
    });
}
```

At that time, you should convert the methods from your `Library` to instance
methods and took that opportunity to encapsulate the `booksByTitle` map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Library library = new Library();
    library.add(5, "Cracking the Coding Interview");
    library.add(3, "Crime and Punishment");
    library.add(2, "Catch-22");

    library.borrowBook("Catch-22");
    library.borrowBook("Catch-22");

    library.printCatalog();
    System.out.println();

    //Client returns the copies
    library.returnBook("Catch-22");
    library.returnBook("Catch-22");

    //Test if catalog has been updated correctly
    library.printCatalog();
    System.out.println();
}
```

At this time, we can wonder what is the role of your `Book` class ? It is just a
wrapper around a `boolean`. You are also printing them as a boolean while, it
would be easier to print the number of copie available and borrowed.

So you can remove the `Book` class and manage two counters in your
`BookCollection`.

```
class BookCollection {
    private int quantity;
    private int available;
    
    // ...
    public boolean borrowBook() { //Borrows a book from the collection
        if ( available>0 ) {
            available -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("All books are borrowed, sorry");
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Now, if you want to apply the *MVC* pattern, your `BookCollection` seems to be a
good candidate for the model while the `Library` looks like a controller once
all call to `System.out` are moved to a dedicated (view) class.

Another improvement would be to use *Exceptions* and query methods instead of
`boolean` to manage exceptional cases.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful suggestions. I have not seen the 'Consumer' interface in Java until now, so I am trying to figure out its role in your reply. in the 'doInCollection' method, what does operation.accept() entail?

Comment: Let's say that `Consumer` is a function that receive one parameter (`BookCollection` in our case) and return nothing. The _lambdas syntax_ (>=Java 8) allow you to create one with a simple syntax: `parameter -> { body }`. I will edit my answer to add this example.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand your example of functional programming because this concept is new to me. With the code `doCollection(bookTitle, collection -> {//Code});` are we telling the program to pass in the result of an accepted `BookCollection` value into a block of code that will later check if a book can be borrowed or not? Thank you again for your response.

Comment: Yes, you have understood it well.